# Setting default value of Name field in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, forms, gravity

In Gravity Forms you can set the default value of a field by using code like:

```
$field->defaultValue = 'My default value';
```

this is mentioned in documentation here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/field-object/

However this doesn't work for the Name field as this is a multi-input field as it contains a first and last name. How do I set the default value of the name field in Gravity Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the Name field is a multi-input field. You must interact with the desired input on a multi-input field. For example, to set the first name, you would do something like this:

`$field->inputs[2]['defaultValue'] = 'Dave';`

Here is the full contents of the `inputs` field property as JSON:

`[{
    "id": "9.2",
    "label": "Prefix",
    "name": "",
    "choices": [{
        "text": "Mr.",
        "value": "Mr.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Mrs.",
        "value": "Mrs.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Miss",
        "value": "Miss",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Ms.",
        "value": "Ms.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Dr.",
        "value": "Dr.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Prof.",
        "value": "Prof.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }, {
        "text": "Rev.",
        "value": "Rev.",
        "isSelected": false,
        "price": ""
    }],
    "isHidden": true,
    "inputType": "radio",
    "defaultValue": "Mr."
}, {
    "id": "9.3",
    "label": "First",
    "name": "",
    "defaultValue": "David"
}, {
    "id": "9.4",
    "label": "Middle",
    "name": "",
    "isHidden": true,
    "defaultValue": "Stover"
}, {
    "id": "9.6",
    "label": "Last",
    "name": "",
    "defaultValue": "Smith"
}, {
    "id": "9.8",
    "label": "Suffix",
    "name": "",
    "isHidden": true,
    "defaultValue": "Jr."
}]`